# How use match in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, match

Im trying to get the uppercase words from a text. How i can use .match() for this?
Example

```
text = "Pediatric stroke (PS) is a relatively rare disease, having an estimated incidence of 2.5–13/100,000/year [1–4], but remains one of the most common causes of death in childhood, with a mortality rate of 0.6/100,000 dead/year [5, 6]"
```

and I need something like:

```
r = /[A-Z]/
puts r.match(text)
```

I never used match and i need a method that gets all uppercase words (Acronym).

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We expect to see where you've searched and why those places didn't help, or to see an example of your code showing what you've tried, and your explanation of why it's not working. As is, you're asking us to write a tutorial for using `match`, which is nicely documented multiple places. Please read "[ask]" then edit your question with the missing information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want acronyms, you can use something like:

```
text = "Pediatric stroke (PS) is a relatively rare disease, having an estimated incidence of 2.5–13/100,000/year [1–4], but remains one of the most common causes of death in childhood, with a mortality rate of 0.6/100,000 dead/year [5, 6]"

text.scan(/\b[A-Z]+\b/)
# => ["PS"]
```

It's important to match entire words, which is where `\b` helps, as it marks word boundaries.

The problem is when your text contains single, stand-alone capital letters:

```
text = "Pediatric stroke (PS) I U.S.A"

text.scan(/\b[A-Z]+\b/)
# => ["PS", "I", "U", "S", "A"]
```

At that point we need a bit more intelligence and foreknowledge of the text content being searched. The question is, are single-letter acronyms valid? If not, then a minor modification will help:

```
text.scan(/\b[A-Z]{2,}\b/)
# => ["PS"]
```

`{2,}` is explained in [the Regexp documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Regexp.html), so read that for more information.

---

> i only want acronym type " (ACRONYM) ", in this case PS

It's not easy to tell what you want by your description. An acronym is defined as:

> An acronym is an abbreviation used as a word which is formed from the initial components in a phrase or a word. Usually these components are individual letters (as in NATO or laser) or parts of words or names (as in Benelux).

according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym). By that definition, lowercase, all caps and mixed case can be valid.

If, you mean you only want all-caps within parenthesis, then you can easily modify the regex to honor that, but you'll fail on other acronyms you could encounter, by either missing ones you should want, or by capturing others you should want to ignore.

```
text = "(PS) (CT/CAT scan)"
text.scan(/\([A-Z]+\)/) # => ["(PS)"]

text.scan(/\([A-Z]+\)/).map{ |s| s[1..-2] } # => ["PS"]

text.scan(/\(([A-Z]+)\)/) # => [["PS"]]
text.scan(/\(([A-Z]+)\)/).flatten # => ["PS"]
```

are varying ways grab the text but this only opens a new can of worms when you look at "[List of medical abbreviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_medical_abbreviations)" and "[Medical Acronyms / Abbreviations](http://www.medindia.net/medical-Abbreviations-and-acronyms/index.asp)".

Typically I'd have a table of the ones I'll accept, use a simple pattern to capture anything that looks like something I'd want, check to see if it's in the table then keep it or reject it. How to do that is for you to figure out as it's a completely different question and doesn't belong in this one.

Comment: thanks you!! but when i have text = "Pediatric stroke (PS) ..The diagnosis is usually by computed tomography (CT/CAT scan) or magnetic resonance ... "   and i do text.scan(/\b[A-Z]{2,}\b/) #=> PS, CT, CAT. and i only want acronym type " (ACRONYM) ", in this case PS.

Comment: You're changing the requirements. It's essential, when you ask a question, that you supply enough information in your question, both as input data, and the expected output. Here's a question back: How can code tell the difference between "PS" and "CT" and "CAT" when they are all acronyms? Code can't tell, only the programmer can based on intimate knowledge of the problem and data, which we don't have, only you do. Again, it's your job to tell us when you ask the question. What is valid, what is not, and what are the rules for telling one from the other?

Answer (score 1):

**To get all words that start with uppercase**, use **[`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan)** with `\b\p{Lu}\w*\b`:

```
text = "Pediatric stroke (PS) is a relatively rare disease, having an estimated incidence of 2.5–13/100,000/year [1–4], but remains one of the most common causes of death in childhood, with a mortality rate of 0.6/100,000 dead/year [5, 6]"
puts text.scan(/\b\p{Lu}\w*\b/).flatten
```

See [demo](http://ideone.com/ghJfZg)

The `String.match()` will only get you the first match, while `scan` will return all matches.

The regex `\b\p{Lu}\w*\b` matches:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `\p{Lu}` - an uppercase Unicode letter
- `\w*` - 0 or more alphanumeric characters
- `\b` - a trailing word boundary

To only match linguistic words (made of *letters*) you can use

```
puts text.scan(/\b\p{Lu}\p{M}*+(?>\p{L}\p{M}*+)*\b/).flatten
```

See [another demo](http://ideone.com/MSsysE)

Here, `\p{Lu}\p{M}*+` matches any Unicode uppercase letter (even a precomposed one as `\p{M}` matches diacritics) and `(?>\p{L}\p{M}*+)*` matches 0 or more letters.

**To only get words in ALLCAPS**, use

```
puts text.scan(/\b(?>\p{Lu}\p{M}*+)+\b/).flatten
```

See [the 3rd demo](http://ideone.com/bU9yyP)

Comment: It's not necessary to use `\w*\b`. `\w*` will pick up word-characters and stop at the same place that `\w*\b` does. Also, `\w` isn't exactly the definition for "words", it's the common definition for "variables", since it contains `[a-z0-9_]` which can cause false-positives. I'd suggest tightening up the recommended pattern. `flatten` shouldn't be needed since you're not using captures.

Comment: I think the `\w` is more than enough in most cases. However, I updated with a solution to only match linguistic words.

Comment: Actually `\w*` is partially correct, but I don't think it answers the OPs need.

Comment: Since the OP is not clear (*i need a method that gets all uppercase words (Acronym)*)  I added two different solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong function for the job. Use [`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [String#match](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-match) for this. It may not be the best way, but you didn't ask if it was. You'd have to do something like this:

```
text.split.map { |s| s.match(/[A-Z]\w*/) }.compact.map { |md| md[0] }
  #=> ["Pediatric", "PS"]
```

If you knew in advance that `text` contained two words beginning with a capital letter, you could write:

```
text.match(/([A-Z]\w*).*([A-Z]\w*)/)
[$1,$2]
  #=> ["Pediatric", "PS"]
```

Note that using a regex is not your only option:

```
text.delete('.,!?()[]{}').split.select { |str| ('A'..'Z').cover?(str[0]) }
  #=> ["Pediatric", "PS"]
```